# Redirect to a file in a WordPress theme directory

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have a site where http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/pdf.php creates a pdf of some content based on what's in a cookie.

That URL is pretty ugly. I'd love the url to simply be http://mysite.com/pdf.

I've tried to use mod_rewrite with no success. E.g. In my .htaccess file I have:

`RewriteRule ^/pdf$ http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/pdf.php`

This just returns a 404. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: you could do something [like this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126582/4771) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
RewriteRule ^pdf$ wp-content/themes/my-theme/pdf.php
```

It looks like removing `http://mysite.com` was the difference.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't strictly a WP question, but this should work - not necessarily the most efficient representation though:

`RewriteRule ^(.*mytheme/)pdf.php http://mysite.com/pdf`

This (http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) is a very useful site for testing rewrite rules.